# How do i make these 4 columns into 3 on resize?

Tags: html, css

In the image here, I'd want column 4 to go under column 3 once the width of the page goes under 800px. I'm assuming I have to do something with media query and width: 100% but I've been unsuccessful so far in getting this done. Any help you guys can provide would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Here's my code:

CSS:

```css
.column-content >h1 {
    margin-left: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
    padding-top: 2em;
}

.three-columns > aside.list-block {
    padding-right: 23em;
    padding-bottom: 3em;
}

.three-columns > aside.list-block > h3 {
    margin-left: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.three-columns > aside.list-block > ul > li {
    margin-left: 20px;
    list-style: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    aside.list-block {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<section class="column-content">
  <h1>Three Columns</h1>
  <div class="three-columns">
    <aside class="list-block">
      <h3>List Heading</h3>
      <ul>
          <li>List Item</li>
          <li>List Item</li>
          <li>List Item</li>
          <li>List Item</li>
          <li>List Item</li>
      </ul>
    </aside>
    <aside class="list-block">
      <h3>List Heading</h3>
      <ul>
          <li>List Item</li>
          <li>List Item</li>
          <li>List Item</li>
          <li>List Item</li>
          <li>List Item</li>
      </ul>
    </aside>
    <aside class="list-block">
      <h3>List Heading</h3>
      <ul>
          <li>List Item</li>
          <li>List Item</li>
      </ul>
    </aside>
    <aside class="list-block">
      <h3>List Heading</h3>
      <ul>
          <li>List Item</li>
          <li>List Item</li>
          <li>List Item</li>
      </ul>
    </aside>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Try Responsive Web Design - Media Queries. 
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Answer (score 0):

change your `css` to

```css
.column-content>h1 {
    margin-left: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
    padding-top: 2em;
}

aside.list-block {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: calc(100% / 4 - 4px);
}

.three-columns>aside.list-block {
    padding-bottom: 3em;
}

.three-columns>aside.list-block>h3 {
    margin-left: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.three-columns>aside.list-block>ul>li {
    margin-left: 20px;
    list-style: none;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
.three-columns>aside.list-block {
    width: calc(100% / 3 - 4px);
}
}
```

```html
<section class="column-content">
            <h1>Three Columns</h1>
            <div class="three-columns">
                <aside class="list-block">
                    <h3>List Heading</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li>List Item</li>
                        <li>List Item</li>
                        <li>List Item</li>
                        <li>List Item</li>
                        <li>List Item</li>
                    </ul>
                </aside>
                <aside class="list-block">
                    <h3>List Heading</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li>List Item</li>
                        <li>List Item</li>
                        <li>List Item</li>
                        <li>List Item</li>
                        <li>List Item</li>
                    </ul>
                </aside>
                <aside class="list-block">
                    <h3>List Heading</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li>List Item</li>
                        <li>List Item</li>
                    </ul>
                </aside>
                <aside class="list-block">
                    <h3>List Heading</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li>List Item</li>
                        <li>List Item</li>
                        <li>List Item</li>
                    </ul>
                </aside>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want like this

```css
.list-block{ width:25%; float:left;}

.column-content>h1 {
    margin-left: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
    padding-top: 2em;
}

.three-columns>aside.list-block {
/*    padding-right: 23em;
    padding-bottom: 3em;*/
}

.three-columns>aside.list-block>h3 {
    margin-left: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.three-columns>aside.list-block>ul>li {
    margin-left: 20px;
    list-style: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    aside.list-block {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
 <section class="column-content">
            <h1>Three Columns</h1>
            <div class="three-columns">
                <aside class="list-block">
                    <h3>List Heading</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li>List Item</li>
                        <li>List Item</li>
                        <li>List Item</li>
                        <li>List Item</li>
                        <li>List Item</li>
                    </ul>
                </aside>
                <aside class="list-block">
                    <h3>List Heading</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li>List Item</li>
                        <li>List Item</li>
                        <li>List Item</li>
                        <li>List Item</li>
                        <li>List Item</li>
                    </ul>
                </aside>
                <aside class="list-block">
                    <h3>List Heading</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li>List Item</li>
                        <li>List Item</li>
                    </ul>
                </aside>
                <aside class="list-block">
                    <h3>List Heading</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li>List Item</li>
                        <li>List Item</li>
                        <li>List Item</li>
                    </ul>
                </aside>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a flexbox for `.three-columns` and align the flex items at the right using `justify-content: flex-end`

```css
.column-content>h1 {
  margin-left: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  padding-top: 2em;
}

.column-content {
  width: 100%;
}

.three-columns {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.three-columns>aside.list-block {
  padding-right: 23em;
  padding-bottom: 3em;
}

.three-columns>aside.list-block>h3 {
  margin-left: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.three-columns>aside.list-block>ul>li {
  margin-left: 20px;
  list-style: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  aside.list-block {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="column-content">
  <h1>Three Columns</h1>
  <div class="three-columns">
    <aside class="list-block">
      <h3>List Heading</h3>
      <ul>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
      </ul>
    </aside>
    <aside class="list-block">
      <h3>List Heading</h3>
      <ul>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
      </ul>
    </aside>
    <aside class="list-block">
      <h3>List Heading</h3>
      <ul>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
      </ul>
    </aside>
    <aside class="list-block">
      <h3>List Heading</h3>
      <ul>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
      </ul>
    </aside>
```

Answer (score 0):

your CSS is the problem. all you need to do is just specify width on different media queries :

```
.column-content>h1 {
    margin-left: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
    padding-top: 2em;
}

.three-columns>aside.list-block {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
}

.three-columns>aside.list-block>h3 {
    margin-left: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.three-columns>aside.list-block>ul>li {
    margin-left: 20px;
    list-style: none;
}



@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
.three-columns>aside.list-block {
    width: 33.333%;
    float: left;
}
}
```

in case of having different amounts of columns you should just use display flex mode